# How to create multiple containers in same pods which have separate deployment.yaml files?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, networking, containers, localhost

tldr: in docker-compose, intercontainer communication is possible via localhost. I want to do the same in k8s, however, I have separate deployment.yaml files for each component. How to link them ?

I have a kubernetes helm package in which there are sub helm packages. The folder structure is as follows ::

```
A
├── Chart.yaml
├── values.yaml
├── charts
│   ├── component1
│   │   ├── Chart.yaml
│   │   ├── templates
│   │   │   ├── configmap.yaml
│   │   │   ├── deployment.yaml
│   │   │   ├── hpa.yaml
│   │   │   ├── ingress.yaml
│   │   │   ├── service.yaml
│   │   │   ├── serviceaccount.yaml
│   │   └── values.yaml
│   ├── component2
│   │   ├── Chart.yaml
│   │   ├── templates
│   │   │   ├── certs.yaml
│   │   │   ├── configmap.yaml
│   │   │   ├── pdb.yaml
│   │   │   ├── role.yaml
│   │   │   ├── statefulset.yaml
│   │   │   ├── pvc.yaml
│   │   │   └── svc.yaml
│   │   ├── values-production.yaml
│   │   └── values.yaml
```

In docker-compose, I was able to communicate between component1 and component2 via ports using localhost.

However, in this architecture, I have separate deployment.yaml files for those components. I know that if I keep them as containers in a single deployment.yaml file, I can communicate via localhost.

Question: How do I put these containers in same pod, provided that they are present in separate deployment.yaml files ?

Comment: Even in Compose, `localhost` normally refers to "the current container", not any other container.  Have you looked at background documentation like [DNS for Services and Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) in the Kubernetes documentation?  It looks like you already have a Service for each (single-container) Deployment and you should use the Service names, not `localhost`.

Comment: @DavidMaze - You opened my eyes!! Even in compose, I'll have to use the container name. This information was deleted in my mind, thanks for restoring.  I think I mixed it with the way it works in kubernetes pods containers <- They can communicate via localhost. 
Also, thanks for pointing out the dns services. Yes, I've used cluster IP dns for communication. That works fine.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. Pods are the smallest deployable unit in kubernetes that consist of one or more containers. All containers inside the pod share the same network namespace (beside others). The containers can only be reached via fqdn or ip. For each container outside a pod "localhost" means something completely different. Similar to running docker compose on different hosts, they can not connect using localhost.

You can use the service's name to have a similar behaviour. Instead of calling `http://localhost:8080` you can simple use `http://component1:8080` to reach component1 from component2, supposing the service in `component1/templates/service.yaml` is named component1 and both are in the same namespace. Generally there is a dns record for every service with the schema `<service>.<namespace>`, e.g. `component1.default` for component1 running in the default namespace. If component2 where in a different namespace you would use `http://component1.default:8080`.

Comment: So you mean it's technically impossible to add a container to a pod using a different deployment.yml file. Right ?

Comment: Exactly. A deployment is basically a wrapper for a replicaset, which is basically a wrapper for an pod via a template. Inside the template you define which containers should run in that pod. If the answer was helpful, please consider voting.